# Error with special characters in url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, url

I have a error getting a url by ajax with the special character of (á ´), I have two selectors when I select South America and Peru did not return anything but tell me this fiebug

GET http://www.example.com/deconsultas/index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais=Per%FA

I have this javascript;

```
$("#listar").click(function(){
    var pais = $("#pais2").val();

    $.get("index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais="+pais, function(data){
        $("#resultados").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

```
public function view()
    {
        $db = new Galerias_Model;

        if (BM_Validations::isAjax()) :
            $this->setTemplate("galerias");
            $this->setFilenames("galerias", 'view.html');

            $pais = htmlentities($_GET['pais']);
            $pais=trim($pais);
            $galerias = $db->getImages($pais);
            if ($galerias) :
                $this->assignVar('ENCONTRO', true);

                $ciudad = "";
                foreach ($galerias as $row) :
                    $mostrarCiudad = false;
                    if ($ciudad!=$row['ciudad']) :
                        $mostrarCiudad = true;
                        $cont = 0;
                    endif;
                    $cont++;

                    $this->assignBlock('galerias', array(
                        'ID' => $row['id'],
                        'MOSTRAR_CIUDAD' => $mostrarCiudad,
                        'CIUDAD' => $row['ciudad'],
                        'IMAGEN' => $row['imagen'],
                        'SALTO_LINEA' => (($cont % 5) == 0)
                    ));

                    $ciudad = $row['ciudad'];
                endforeach;
            endif;

            $this->tpl->display('galerias');
        endif;
        die();
    }
```

And this is the php that receive that url, its seems be something like .htaccess?

I have this:

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks 
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /deconsultas/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=$1&id=$2&titulo=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.dc$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=operador&url=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^panel/([^/]*)$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=panel&action=$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)$ /deconsultas/index.php?controller=admin&action=$1&inactivos [L]


<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be building your own querystring.  Let jQuery do that for you.

Comment: @Diego Use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23434651/227299)

Answer (score 0):

When building a query string, you have to url encode each component, for example `á` encodes to `%C3%A1`

```
$("#listar").click(function(){
    var pais = $("#pais2").val();
    var urlEncodedPais = encodeURIComponent(pais);
    $.get("index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais=" + urlEncodedPais , function(data){
        $("#resultados").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

An even better ways is to let jQuery do it for you https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

```
$("#listar").click(function(){
    var pais = $("#pais2").val();
    var params = {
       controller: 'galerias',
       action: 'view',
       pais: pais
    };
    $.get("index.php?"+ $.param(params), function(data){
        $("#resultados").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note that this also applies to key value names, so you could have the parameter be called `país` if you wanted (but I wouldn't recommend it)

```
jQuery.param({"país": 'Índia'})
> "pa%C3%ADs=%C3%8Dndia"
```

Comment: Its say: GET http://www.xxx.com/deconsultas/index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais=Per%C3%BA

Comment: The get generate me that url

Comment: @Diego I still can't make sense of whatever you're trying to ask. I gave you an answer. If it's not what you're looking for, please explain exactly what part of the answer does not work for you. I know English is not your first language but you have to be try to more precise in your question.

Comment: I use your code, but when I click in "Listar" its generate that url that I comment, if I select Perú the url is this one: http://www.xxx.com/deconsultas/index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais=Per%C3%BA

Comment: @Diego If you use the code I listed, the URL it creates is `index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais=Per%C3%BA` You can see this here http://jsfiddle.net/9XKbN/1/

Comment: Yes but I want to create  index.php?controller=galerias&action=view&pais=Perú , its possible?

Comment: @Diego I'm not sure what you don't understand. You cannot send 'ú' in the URL, you **have** to url encode it, that's why it doesn't work currently

Comment: But that url search Perú at the db and get all the images of Perú how I  can do that?